# Google Drive getToken class not found exception

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I have integrated Google Drive in my android app and when I debug the app on the device with the android version 2.3.6 I get ClassNotFoundException when I call this:

```
mCredential.getToken();
```

where mCredential is set like that:

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

I see that in my Debug tab:

```
Thread [<13> Thread-15] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
PathClassLoader.findClass(String) line: 240 
PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 551   
PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 511    
GoogleAuthUtil.f(Context) line: not available   
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Context, String, String, Bundle) line: not available    
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Context, String, String) line: not available    
GoogleAccountCredential.getToken() line: 192    
GoogleDrive.checkIfUserIsAuthenticated(Activity, boolean) line: 411 
GoogleDrive.access$4(GoogleDrive, Activity, boolean) line: 403  
GoogleDrive$1.run() line: 98
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was pulling my hair out over this one too.  For me, the ClassNotFoundException was because of a missing string resource.  Apparently Google play services includes resources and must be imported as a library project as opposed to just adding the .jar as a dependency.  Instructions to do so in Eclipse are here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Once I completed those instructions I got a build error saying that multiple dexed libs contained certain classes or something to that effect.  That error turned out to be because I now had two references to google-play-services.jar.  To fix that error, under the project explorer view, right click on the bin directory and click delete.  This will get rid of the dexedLibs folder with multiple copies of google-play-services.jar.  At this point I had a reference to google-play-services.jar in the root of my project and also under "Android Dependencies".  I right clicked on the reference in the root of my project and then went to Build Path -> Remove From Build Path to get rid of it.